# R tibble dataframe slice and rollapply function

Tags: r, xts, tibble

I am writing a script to calculate the standard deviation of S&P500 and want to compare the rolling standard deviation to the long term average of the SD.

I can make my codes work but seems kind of clumsy. I want to ask two questions to make my code easier to understand.

1. Suppose I have two indices. Can I use one line of code to find the annualised SD for both tickers? Now I have to do it ticker by ticker

```
GSPC.new <- merge(GSPC.new,rollapply(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.ret, 252, sd))
```

2. It is easier to slice a xts object. Can I do the same in tibble dataframe?

```
gspc.avg10yr <- mean(na.omit(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std.annualised["2011/2022"]))
```

All code below can be executed directly in RStudio directly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

tickers <- c("^HSI","^GSPC")
getSymbols(Symbols = tickers,
           src = "yahoo",
           index.class = "POSIXct",
           from = "1997-01-01")

GSPC.new <- na.omit(GSPC)
GSPC.new <- merge(GSPC.new, dailyReturn(GSPC.new$GSPC.Adjusted))
colnames(GSPC.new)[7] <- "GSPC.adj.ret"
GSPC.new <- merge(GSPC.new,rollapply(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.ret, 252, sd)) # how to annualised both tickers in one line
colnames(GSPC.new)[8] <- "GSPC.adj.std"
GSPC.new <- merge(GSPC.new, GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std*sqrt(252))
colnames(GSPC.new)[9] <- "GSPC.adj.std.annualised"
GSPC.new.tbl <- as_tibble(fortify(GSPC.new))
p.gspc <- ggplot(GSPC.new.tbl, aes(x=Index,y=GSPC.adj.std.annualised))
p.gspc + geom_line()
gspc.avg10yr <- mean(na.omit(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std.annualised["2011/2022"])) # is it possible to do in tibble way?
gspc.avg15yr <- mean(na.omit(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std.annualised["2006/2022"]))
gspc.avg20yr <- mean(na.omit(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std.annualised["2001/2022"]))
gspc.avg25yr <- mean(na.omit(GSPC.new$GSPC.adj.std.annualised["1997/2022"]))
p.gspc + geom_line()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = gspc.avg10yr, color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = gspc.avg15yr, color = "blue")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = gspc.avg20yr, color = "green")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = gspc.avg25yr, color = "black")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the ticker data in environment, e, iterate over the ticker names calculating the returns in a list, ret.list, and then form that into an xts object, ret.  From that calculate the standardized returns annualized, std_ann, as an xts object.

To create the plot create a grid data frame g and from it data frame Means with columns Series, col (colors) and means to be used in geom_hline. autoplot will use Series to refer to the facets and geom_hline will use the Series column in Means to match each horizontal line to the appropriate facet.

Only the packages listed below (and the packages they depend on) are used.

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

tickers <- c("^HSI","^GSPC")
yrs <- c(red = 10, green = 15, blue = 20, black = 25)

getSymbols(Symbols = tickers, env = e <- new.env(), from = "1997-01-01")

ret.list <- Map(function(nm) dailyReturn(na.omit(Ad(e[[nm]]))), ls(e))
ret <- setNames(do.call("merge", ret.list), names(ret.list))
std_ann <- rollapplyr(ret, 252, function(x) sqrt(252) * sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))

g <- expand.grid(Series = names(std_ann), col = names(yrs), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
meansfun <- function(Series, col) {
    st <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(2022-yrs[[col]]-1))
    mean(window(std_ann[, Series], start = st), na.rm = TRUE)
}
Means <- transform(g, means = mapply(meansfun, Series, col))

autoplot(std_ann) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = means), Means, col = Means$col) +
  xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]